# How to Make Automator not Stop or Glitch when Moving Another Slider

Tags: manipulate

The following code creates an animated graphic that auto-rotates, and I can change the view by mouse-dragging the graphic without causing it to stop or glitch. It works great. However, when I use the slider to control the argument of the sine function, it stops and then picks up when I let go of the slider.  Is it possible to make this behave smoothly?  I want to do this for all my Manipulate functions as it brings the graphics alive.

```
Manipulate[
 
 gr = {
   Graphics3D[{}],
   Plot3D[Sin[a x y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]};
 
 Show[(g |-> 
     Map[(GeometricTransformation[#, 
         RotationTransform[Dynamic[\[Theta]], {0, 0, 1}, center]] &), 
      g]) /@ gr, PlotRange -> 4.5, SphericalRegion -> True, 
  Boxed -> False],
 
 {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi, ControlType -> Animator, AnimationRate -> .03},
 {a, 1, 2},
 
 Initialization :> {
   center = 
    Mean /@ (PlotRange /. 
       AbsoluteOptions[
        Graphics3D[{Arrow[Tube[{{-3.75, 0, 0}, {3.75, 0, 0}}, .01]], 
          Arrow[Tube[{{0, -3.75, 0}, {0, 3.75, 0}}, .01]], 
          Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, -3.75}, {0, 0, 3.75}}, .01]]}], 
        PlotRange])}]
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't stop or glitch on `$Version "13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"`. But your posted code doesn't effect the arrows for the axes in my version.

Comment: @rowsi Really?  As you move the "a" slider, it continues to rotate and do it smoothly?  I'm on MacOS 13.1 on M1Mac  running Mathematica 13.2.   For me, it stops the rotation and jumps when I let go.  Bummer.  Maybe it's an OS thing.

Comment: MMA 13.2 on Windows 10 It does not stop.